# HP ProLiant DL320e G8 v2 - Install CentOS or Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation

I just bought a HP ProlLiant DL320e G8 v2 and I am trying to install CentOS or Ubuntu Server on it from a USB. The problem is that I do not have any option for this in Intelligent Provisioning (the only options are Windows, Red Hat Linux, Open Suse Enterprise, VMWare ESXI/vSphere Custom Image and VMWare ESX Custom Image.

I changed the boot order in bios and I've put USB first but it does not boot. What can I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use [**Intelligent Provisioning**](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/intelligentprovisioning/) to install Linux onto this server. That's for streamlined installations of ESXi, Windows and such.

You say you're installing from "a USB". Is that a USB CD or DVD drive? A USB thumb drive? What did you place onto the media? An .ISO?

- Try burning a CD and using the internal drive.
- If there's no internal drive, try an external drive.
- Use a supported version of the Linux distribution of your choice and try installing from the ILO interface.